# Get File Size of Image in Rust

Tags: rust

How can you determine the file size of an image using the image crate in rust?

```rust
let img = image::open("imgs/2.jpg").unwrap();
let myBytes = &img.to_bytes();
//get the number of bytes?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `image` crate deal with images, let standard library's `fs` module deal with the file system:

```
let imgSize = std::fs::metadata("imgs/2.jpg").unwrap().len();
```

Also look for other capabilities of [`std::fs::Metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.Metadata.html) struct

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2023 you can consider to use also the `std::path::PathBuf` class.

Here is an example on how you can read the file size in bytes:

```
Welcome to evcxr. For help, type :help
>> use std::path::PathBuf;
>> let path = PathBuf::from("root/images/mountain-landscape.jpg");
>> let len = path.metadata().unwrap().len();
>> println!("File length: {len}");
File length: 421631
```

or in one line:

```
>> std::path::PathBuf::from("root/images/mountain-landscape.jpg").metadata().unwrap().len()
421631
```